# How to fetch value of multiselect dropdown in Laravel 8?

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel

I have this code for multiselect dropdown

```
<select id="kit" name="tool_id[]" multiple class="form-control single-select selectpicker">
    <option value="">Select Tool Name</option>
    <?php foreach($tools as $tool){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $tool->id;?>"><?php echo $tool->name;?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

I can insert data in database ,but unable to retrieve on show blade

[image]

value stores in database like this in array

Help me to retrieve array value from MySql DB

Retrieve array value from data base in laravel

Comment: what does the data type of the column `tool_id` ?

Comment: Varchar  tool_id value comes from another  table on integer  unable to store in array form

Comment: you should store it as a `json string` then just convert them in an array when you fetch it

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing an array, you can use **in_array** to achieve the result you are looking for:

```
// I will assume here that you are passing a list of IDs from view
// I think in your example its "tool_id"

<option value="{{$tool->id}}" {{in_array($tool->id, $listOfIds) ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$tool->name}}</option>
```

You can read more examples from https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Also you do not need to call `<?php //code ?>` in blade files, you can simply use `{{ //code }}` to render it, you can read more on blade syntax from https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade

Good luck!

Comment: "tool_id" => "["11","13"]"

Just want to retrieve that array in show blade

Comment: @POONAMKHATRI post your controller function, and I will add more to my answer to give you a full solution, your tool_id is stored correctly as an ARRAY, even though you set it as a string, in your SQL DB it shows that its stored as an array

Comment: $input['tool_id'] = json_encode($input['tool_id']);

Store code

Answer (score 0):

If you can fetch the value of `tool_id` from the database, use this.

```
{!! Form::select('tool_id', $yourOptionArray, $toolIds, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
```

By default, this will add `selected` keywords to `11` and `13`.

Answer (score 0):

As the value of the select tag is being saved as an array, this can be simply done with the in_array condition as mentioned below:

```
<option value="{{ $tool->id }}" @if(in_array($tool->id,$IDsList)) selected @endif>{{ $tool->name }}</option>
```

Assuming the $IDsList (passed to the view blade from controller) have the value stored for the $tool->id

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).